# Click on link and have it loaded in a <div>

Tags: php, html

I have the following code.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: gary
 * Date: 3/23/16
 * Time: 05:01
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="Default Page">
    <meta name="author" content="Gary Ehrenfeld">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Hive Management</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<div CLASS="h-banner">
            <h1 class="h1-white">&nbspHive Management</h1>

</div>

<div class="v-banner">
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <h4>
            <ul class="nav nav-pils nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#" class="h1-white">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="h1-white">My&nbspYards</a></li>
                <li><a href="hives.php" class="h1-white">My&nbspHives</a></li>
                <li><a href="inspections.php" target="content" class="h1-white">Inspections</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="h1-white">Hive&nbspEvents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="h1-white">Harvest</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="h1-white">Feeding</a></li>
            </ul>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Main Window
</div>
```

I when I click on a link I would like that link to open in the main window div but not sure how to do that.
I do not know if javascript is the way because I do not know javascript and how to use it in php.

Comment: You can do it with ajax, just grab file with your content and on success insert it into div

Comment: You need to use javascript in order to dynamically load content in to your page, you need to fire an ajax call, get the content and load it in the `<div>Main Window</div>` from javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use JavaScript for this, here is one simple example :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".nav li a").on( "click",function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var page = $(this).attr('href');

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: page,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#yourdiv").html(msg);
            }
        });
});})
</script>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Javascript. Where do I put it and how do I call it form the link?

Comment: So this is jquery so you will need to add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head of your html, after that the stuff I posted you can add anywhere, this code works when ever you click on anchor tag in navigation, it gets href attribute from html and puts it in page variable and then with $.ajax gets that file from your folder and inserts it in your div, you just have to change where you want it to be inserted `$("#yourdiv").html(msg);`  change yourdiv with id of div.

Comment: what to i change here  <li><a href="hives.php" class="h1-white">My&nbspHives</a></li> I changed my <div> to <div id""yourdiv">

Comment: div with `id='yourdiv'` is div where you will return your page and `href='hives.php'` has to be page that you want to import to your div

Comment: sorry for being so dumb can you give me an example using my code from my first post.

Comment: just add `id='yourdiv'` to `<div>Main Window</div>` and it should work

Comment: I change it <div id='yourdiv'> and it opens in a new window. Not in the <div>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107366/discussion-between-gehrenfeld-and-marko-kunic).

Comment: <div id='yourdiv'></div> want to make sure that is correct.